# VB.NET connect to local website and trigger an event (button)

Tags: html, vb.net, events, triggers, onclick

I really have no piece of code I can show you, because I have no idea how to even begin coding this.

I have to do the following with VB.NET:

1. Connect to a local website ( https://10.0.0.55/ )
2. Trigger an event on that specific page (button onClick)

   ```
   <div onClick="mySubmit('webEvent=START&webSector=0')">START</div>
   ```

The only thing I know at the moment is that you can connect to the website through the WebClient.

```
    Dim webClient As New WebClient()
    webClient.BaseAddress = "http://10.0.0.55/"
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Jens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a WebBrowser control:

Navigate to the address:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://10.0.0.55/")
```

The in the DocumentCompleted event you can invoke a click. Something like this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").InvokeMember("click")
```

Comment: Woah, thanks for the quick reply! I'm going to test it right away.

Comment: is it possible to fire the onClick without going to the element? Every button on the page has the same event ( "mySubmit('webEvent=&param&)" )
It would be awesome if I could just sent the correct param and fire the event right away, since the buttons don't have ID's on them and I can't change the HTML file since it's not mine.

Comment: You have to click *something* on the page. You can always use `GetElementsByTagName` instead

Comment: Yeah I understand, but the page itself is really badly written. It's not even a button, it's just a div with an onclick..

Yeah I understand, but the page is really bad written. 

<div class="track_Btn"><div><div><div onClick="mySubmit('webEvent=START')"> <div><img class="sprites img_start" src="/img/img_trans.gif"></div> <div><p>START</p></div> </div></div></div></div> 

I hope you can read the code above.

Comment: Just use GetElementsByTagName and enumerate through the results till you find the one you want